# Synonym for photos.app to photos

Tags: feature-request, tags

All of the newest questions in the [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) tag refer to the new Apple Photos application. [photos.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos.app) refers to the same thing. Could someone with enough reputation please make [photos.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos.app) be a synonym of [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) to group these together?

Admittedly, some older [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) threads are about Aperture or iPhoto, but Apple is the one to have introduced the confusing naming, and Apple Photos does represent the successor application.

Answer (score 3):

From the [tags page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags):

> **photos** x 590
>
> Photographs and photography

And:

> **photos.app** x 81
>
> The Apple photo manager and editor and successor to iPhoto and Aperture. Introduced in 2015.

Making **photos** a synonym of **photos.app** has the potential to mis-tag 590 questions now. Questions that pre-date the existence of the Photos app from Apple and have nothing to do with the tool.

Our convention has been to use `.app` on tags to denote the Apple product with the noun.

Violating this convention in this particular case does not, in my opinion, sound like a good idea.

Comment: Please see my new suggestion (entered as it's own possible answer).

Comment: @dankohn I considered this as well, but I think the harm in linking all photos posts to photos app outweighs the benefits of having people continually mis-tagging posts. Over time, I believe people will get the difference and only tag things photos.app when it's about that app specifically and use the generic tag in most cases.

Comment: @bmike You have too good a view of people - I think most will just hit the first tag that matches e.g. photo - using photography will force them to  make a choice. Most people seem not to spend time learning conventions - in general in computing I jayvee found that conventions work only when backed up with tools or processes to enforce them

Comment: @Mark I was vague - the people that will care are the editors that make the majority of the edits here. No one will change most of the wrong uses, but when a question gets lots of views, that detail will bug someone so much that they make the change and all the high quality/high vote questions about photos.app will get tagged correctly. (IMO of course ;-)

Comment: See this edit http://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/106228 everything correct but Photos.app

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ian C.'s response:

Would it be possible to rename [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) to [photography](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) and then create a new [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) tag that was a synonym to [photos.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos.app)? That would:

1. Continue the convention of using '.app' for Apple products.
2. Maintain existing and future photography-related questions with their own tag, that does not conflict with the name of a (new) Apple product.
3. Enable most new contributors who are likely to just enter [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) to (via a synonym) get their questions tagged correctly.

Comment: This probably should be a new question or a discussion in the better tags chat room on the site. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2510/better-tags-for-ask-different