# Rename [photos] to [photographs]

Tags: discussion, tags

Sorry, I couldn't think up of a burnination zinger.

[photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) is ambiguous, as people may think it refers to the photos OS X application.

It should be renamed to [photographs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photographs) to avoid ambiguity.

There was a previous request to change it as an answer by the OP of [Synonym for photos.app to photos](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/synonym-for-photos-app-to-photos) , but underneath that answer was a comment suggesting using the tag chat room (now frozen) or another question to discuss it.

Comment: That won't make a difference as people will select photos rather than photographs

Comment: How about a new tag for Photos the app as Photos.app and an explicit mention in the tag descriptor for the existing photos tag?